# Ints sent over UDP are bytes

Tags: python, arrays

I am sending ints from MaxMSP on a Mac via a UDP send to Python running on a RaspberryPi Zero. The ints are then being sent to a dot matrix display (Micro Dot Phat) using its own library.

The problem I have is that the ints are being displayed as;

b'int\x00,i\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00

both when printed and when written as a string to the display.

I have spent a couple of days googling this and have tried the struct.unpack, int.from_bytes and decode('utf-8') methods as suggested on several related questions but cannot seem to extract the (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc) that I would like on the display.

The display requires a write_string so I think I need to convert the byte format either to a python int then a string or straight to a string.

Any help would be appreciated.

code as requested;

```
import socket

import struct

UDP_IP = "My Pi's IP"
UDP_PORT = 'My chosen port"
mystring = ""

serverSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
serverSOCK.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
   data, addr = serverSock.recvfrom(1024)

   mystring = str(data)
```

this allows strings sent from MaxMSP to to be displayed as expected on the display but not ints

```
   write_string(mystring, kerning=False)
   show()
```

this sends to dotmatrix display

```
   print (mystring)
```

Methods I have attempted to convert the bytes to ints without any luck;

```
data = data.decode('utf-8')

struct.unpack('<' + 'B'*len(data), data)

int.from_bytes(data, byte order='little')

data = struct.unpack(data) [0]
```

Comment: Show us code, code that proves you tried something. This is not a coding as a service platform!

Comment: Asked question on my mac, the code is on my Pi so not just a case of copy and pasting the code... not expecting coding on demand just some general pointers as to which method might work... however will post code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the `int.from_bytes` method, but you need to slice off the three initial b"int" bytes from your `bytes` string.

```
bstring = b'int\x00,i\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
n = int.from_bytes(bstring[3:], 'little')
print(n)
```

**output**

```
6892544
```

If that's not the correct integer, then you'll need to find out how that data has been encoded.

---

It looks like the `\x00,i` is also part of the header, so we need to adjust the slicing operation to

```
n = int.from_bytes(bstring[6:], 'little')
```

Comment: Hi and thanks a lot for the help, the sent interger was 0, so I will have to do a bit of research on the original byte's encoding

Comment: @dvectR Oh. Perhaps the `\x00,i` is also part of the header. So you'd need to slice that off as well, eg `int.from_bytes(bstring[6:], 'little')`. If that doesn't work, add a few more examples of integers and their encodings to your question & I'll try to figure out the real encoding format. Eg, 1, 2, 3, 10, 100, 1000. And some negative numbers too, if they are permitted.

Comment: You were right re the \x00,i being part of the header, with the changes you suggested the int stream is now arriving perfectly. Thanks again for your help with this.